# Missing document request

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

I received a request for [another](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37963/lecture-notes-by-thurston-on-tiling) long-lost document:

> I am wondering if there is any way I
>   might obtain a copy of
>
> The geometry of circles: Voronoi
>   diagrams, Moebius transformations,
>   convex hulls, Fortune's algorithm, the
>   cut locus, and parametrization of
>   shapes W.P. Thurston Technical Report,
>   Princeton University, 1986.
>
> Is there a scanned version somewhere
>   or might some library stock it?

Can anyone help out?

For context: I gave a series of presentations in a EECS course with Dave Dobkin, and I wrote these notes to go with it.  It was fun material at the time, but the notes were only moderately distributed.

Comment: While people are at it, there was a paper that used to be distributed with the video "Outside-In" explaining the math in it (I think that it was coauthored by Thurston and Silvio Levi).  Does anyone have a copy of it?

Comment: @Andy Putname:  Outside In is available from A.K. Peters, as a DVD, together with Not Knot and the video supplement *Making Waves* by Silvio Levy.  (You can also still order videotape versions). Here is the link:

http://akpeters.com/product.asp?ProdCode=4537

The videotape should be available at many libraries, and probably the supplement.

Comment: Both "Outside In" and "Not Knot" are also available online at various places.  For some reason I had convinced myself a while ago that it was no longer for sale [and none of the institutions I've been at have owned copies] -- thanks for pointing out the link!

Comment: A quibble with "also available online":  The link I gave *is* online. Sometimes Amazon (http://www.amazon.com/Outside-Not-Knot-Geometry-Center/dp/1568814534/ref=sr_1_1?s=gateway&ie=UTF8&qid=1285127363&sr=8-1) *Hurry! only two in stock!* and Barnes&Noble (http://productsearch.barnesandnoble.com/search/results.aspx?WRD=Outside+In+Not+Knot) have had ridiculous expected shipping times, which is why I went to the publisher website, but it looks like they may currently work in a reasonable time.

Comment: What I meant is that I've seen free streaming versions available, though I suppose that their legal status is probably dubious.  For example, here's "Not Knot" : 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGLPbSMxSUM

Comment: By the way, if you want that link deleted then just let me know and I will do so.

Comment: @Andy Putnam, I just mininterpreted your meaning.  I don't have any problem (personally) with giving people links to the streaming versions --- I've done it myself. The video quality is of course much better on the DVD; the two forms have different roles. When we made the videos, our purpose was never commercial, but to show people aspects of mathematics they may not have encountered, and to enable them to catch on, enjoy and become interested in things that might have made no sense. My personal stake is that I want interested people to be able to see them.

Comment: Might I also add a request here for Bill Thurston's 1985 preprint "On the combinatorics and dynamics of iterated rational maps", which I've seen cited in quite a few papers but cannot find?

Comment: @jc: "On the combinatorics and dynamics of iterated rational maps"
has has now been edited and updated by Dierk Schleicher, and is published in the volume **Complex Dynamics: Families and Friends**
which he edited (associated with thte John Hubbard 60th birthday conference).

Comment: @Bill Thurston: Thank you, it looks like a beautiful book, and I've just placed an order for it!

Comment: @jc: My library didn't have *Complex Dynamics* (Bill suggested it in another thread), so I purchased it for myself. It is delightful, from the opening classic paper by Thurston on laminations to the closing 17th chapter whose last figure is a beautiful image of the Löbell 10 polyhedron.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the `.tex` not quite "as-is," but modified minimally so that it will compile: [`DTnotes.tex`](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/MathOverflow/DTnotes.tex).
And here is `.pdf` produced by compiling that `.tex`:  [`DTnotes.pdf`](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/MathOverflow/DTnotes.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Joseph O'Rourke did what I should have thought to do myself: he wrote to David Dobkin, who still had a copy of a version of these notes in his email.  I haven't yet gone over them to make them compile with a current tex environment, but [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5390048/notes.tex) is a copy as-is. When I have a chance to fix it, I'll substitute a better version and I'll consider whether to put it in a more visible spot.